# how to change the color of the letters to white only when clicked

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, this, addeventlistener

how to change the colour of the letters to white only when clicked and then changes to the beginning when it is no longer clicked.

I am really thank you for your help.

```
var drum = document.querySelectorAll("button"),
  i;

for (i = 0; i <= drum.length; ++i) {
  var drumi = drum[i];

  var drummy = drumi.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.style.color = "white";
  });
}
```

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing CSS should do, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Just using CSS:

```css
button:active {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use 2 different events

1. `onmousedown` for when the user click on the element
2. `onmouseup` for when the user release the mouse button

The suggested code would look like something like this:

```
var drum = document.querySelectorAll("button"),
  i;

for (i = 0; i <= drum.length; ++i) {
  var drumi = drum[i];

  drumi.addEventListener("onmousedown", function() {
    this.style.color = "white";
  });

  drumi.addEventListener("onmouseup", function() {
    this.style.color = "black"; // put the original color here
  });
}
```

Comment: This will not work because the button is initially triggered by a click event.

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked, the text turns white, then black. Is this what you wanted?

JS

```
let clicked = true
let turnWhite = (button) => {
  clicked = !clicked
  clicked ? button.style.color = "white" : button.style.color = "black"
}
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="turnWhite(this)">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Peter Collingridge has the best answer. But if you want to do it in js you could do it like this.

```
<button onmousedown="turn(this,'blue')" onmouseup="turn(this, 'red')" style="color:red">hello</button>

<script>
    function turn(element, color) {
        element.style.color = color;
    }
</script>
```